# Scope in NodeJS / Firebase promise

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to develop a NodeJS app connecting to Firebase. I can connect successfully, but I'm unable to figure how to manage the scope in the `then` call.

I'm using NodeJS 6.9.2

My test implementation looks like this:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const fb = require('firebase')

class FireGateway extends EventEmitter {

constructor() {
    super();
    if ( this.instance ) {
      return this.instance;
    }
    // INIT
    var fbConfig = {
        apiKey: "xxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/"
        };
    fb.initializeApp(fbConfig)
    this.instance = this;
    this.testvar = "aaa";   
}

login() {
    fb.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword ("email", "pwd")
    .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
    }).then( function(onresolve, onreject) {
        if (onresolve) {            
            console.log(this.testvar);
            // "Cannot read property 'testvar' of undefined"
           this.emit('loggedin');
           // error as well
           }
    })
}

}


module.exports = FireGateway;

------
...
var FireGateway = require('./app/fireGateway');
this.fireGW = new FireGateway();
this.fireGW.login();
....
```

Any idea how can I manage it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback passed to then is being called asynchronously from another context, so the `this` doesn't correspond to the instantiated object.

Using ES6 `arrow functions` you can keep your object context, since an arrow function does not create its own `this` context.

By the way, the syntax you are using in the `then` method is not correct, `then` accepts two callbacks with one argument each one. Check the syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).
The `catch` before the `then` is not necessary as well I think, it would make more sense to put it at the end.

It would be something like this:

```
login() {
    fb.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("email", "pwd")
    .then(
    (onResolve) => {
        console.log(this.testvar);
        this.emit('loggedin');
    },
    (onReject) = > {
        // error handling goes here
    });
}
```

On the other hand, it seems `login` method is doing an asynchronous operation, so you might want to wait for it to finish in your code. I would make the `login` method return a Promise, so you can wait for it outside:

```
login() {
    return fb.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("email", "pwd")
    ...
}
```